# У меня есть главный контент В каком теге html я должен вместить его

Tags: html5

```
<?>
<h1>...</h1>
<p>...</p>
</?>
```

Comment: Советую больше ознакомится з html. Это базовые вопросы, ответ на который можна найти в первой ссылке гугла.

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого тега "главный контент" в html, это определяется макетом, который создал верстальщик.

Самый типичный вариант в современной практике - это обернуть в `<div>`, присвоив ему id (или класс) main_content. Ранее (когда было принято верстать таблицами) это мог бы быть `<table>` с соответствующей обвязкой, но так уже верстают только самые замшелые динозавры.

Также в современной практике может использоваться `<section>` для более детальной проработки, такой стиль характерен для лэндингообразных страниц на базе twitter bootstrap. Но это как раз не совсем ваш случай, там на странице находится несколько секций, а вы хотите один блок для "самого главного" контента.

Comment: Почему не main-то?

Answer (score 0):

Это риторический вопрос, вообще контент можно разместить например в теге div с классом content. Если речь идет конкретно о каком-то текстовом контенте/статьи - в теге article, в соответствии с стандартами html5

Answer (score 0):

Логично, что главный контент (уникальный для данной страницы) следует размещать в теге `main`, чьё название именно так и переводится - "главный". Ну и следует не забывать, что такой тег на странице может быть всего один и в него не должны попадать меню, элементы навигации и другие подобные элементы.